# How is spamassasin called by amavisd-new?

Tags: linux, email, spamassassin, amavis

I initially thought amavisd passed incoming email message through to spamassin via the spamd daemon but now the spamd daemon is down on my new test email relay and the messages are still being flagged as spam and headers are added correctly.

I gooogled around but I can't find a clear answer as to how amavis comunicates/uses spamassin.

Does any of you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calls it up via perl, no deamon required.

Answer (score 5):

Amavisd-new uses SpamAssassin's perl modules directly, so all the spam processing is done directly in the amavisd processes.