# unable to switch Spamassasin module loading in amavisd-new

Tags: perl, spamassassin

I have a default installation of 'amavisd-new' and with it an old SpamAssassin installation version 3.2.5.

Now I have compiled Spamassassin version 3.3.1 from source and installed it at a custom location.

How can i load my compiled Spamassassin 3.3.1 to the original 'amavisd-new' so that it skips the old version and takes the new version

The answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/24626/how-is-spamassasin-called-by-amavisd-new) suggests that 'amavisd-new' uses SpamAssassin's perl modules directly.

How to do the switching?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma